# 301 redirect with "?" query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string, http-status-code-301

Sorry I can't quite find an example to help me

I have http://domainname.com/embed.js?pname=wordpress&pver=2.70
and I want to 301 redirect to http://domainname.com/

I've tried several things from several examples, but I can't quite figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.isitebuild.com/301-redirect.htm

Comment: Retagged to remove `query` (which is DB related) and add `query-string` which is URL related.  More of the right kind of eyeballs!

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how restrictive you want the redirect.   I am assuming that you mean a redirect to *domainname**2*** since I can't see the logic of doing what you ask otherwise. For all embed.js:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
RewwriteRule  embed.js http://domainname2.com/embed.js?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301]
```

but if you want to limit this redirect to pname=wordpress options for example then insert the following directive before the `RewwriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}  \bpname=wordpress\b
```